# Convert integer list into tree in F#

Tags: list, f#, tree

I'm new to F# and would like to know how to convert a simple integer list into a tree.

```
let lst =[1;2;3;4]
type Tree=
 |Leaf of int
 |Node Tree * Tree
```

list should convert  to tree like this ---> Leaf 1,Node(Leaf 2),Node(Node(Leaf 3,Leaf 4))

Comment: What exactly is the result that you'd like to get? Do you want to get a balanced tree?

Comment: I agree with Tomas--it's hard to tell what sort of tree you're hoping to output. If this is homework, then maybe you should share what you've already tried.

Answer (score 2):

The output that you want to get in your answer is a bit poorly formatted, but my interpretation is that you are trying to build a balanced binary tree. To do this recursively, you need to split the input list in two halves and then recursively build tree from the left and the right halves.

This is a bit tricky, because splitting a functional list in halves is not that simple. In practice, you could probably turn your data into an array and use that, but if you want a functional solution you can use:

```
type Tree = Leaf of int | Node of Tree * Tree

let rec half marker acc xs = 
  match xs, marker with
  | x::xs, _::_::marker -> half marker (x::acc) xs
  | x::xs, _::[] -> List.rev (x::acc), xs
  | xs, _ -> List.rev acc, xs
```

The trick in the `half` function is that it iterates over the list and keeps two copies of the list. From one (called `marker`), it takes two elements at each step and so by the time this list is empty, you have reached the middle of the original list where we take just one element at each step.

Now you can write a simple recursive function to build a tree

```
let rec makeTree = function
  | [] -> failwith "Does not work on empty lists"
  | [x] -> Leaf x
  | xs ->  let l, r = half xs [] xs
           Node(makeTree l, makeTree r)
```

Comment: Thanks Tomas, I tried with few methods using for loops but was unsuccessful.